# Scrapy.Request() doesn't work in parse method

Tags: python, scrapy

I have an issue the following code in my Spider-Class:

```
  def parse(self, response):
        item = ResponseItem();
        item['url'] = response.headers["Location"]
        item['status'] = response.status


        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.txt'
        with open (filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write("%r" %response.status)
            f.write("\r\n")
            f.write("%s" %item['url'])

        return scrapy.Request("http://www.google.com/", callback=self.testparse)

def testparse(self, response): ...
```

Scrapy/Python doesn't do the Request defined in the parse-Method.
I'm quite new to Scrapy and Python, so can anyone tell me, what I've made wrong?

(The request-URL is just an example)

Comment: If you can share your console log, with LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG that would help a lot. Why do you say it _doesn't do_ the Request? Could the request be filtered? (already issued maybe?)

Comment: Can you post the full spider code? Btw, keep in mind that Scrapy filters duplicated requests.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late response, but I have found my solution.
Idiotically I forgot to set the right allowed domains...